# Spring mvc dropdown box- bind list of options object(not selected option) to controller

Tags: spring-mvc, dropdownbox

I have a drop down box in my jsp with a search button. On the click of search button on the same jsp below this drop down and search button i am displaying a data table which took the selected value from the drop down and displays all the results matching the key.

Jsp:

```
<form:form action="/search" modelAttribute="myModel" method="post">
<form:select path="categorySearched">
    <form:option option="0" label="--Select--">
    <form:options items="${myModel.categoryList}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
</form:select>

<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form:form>

<form:form action="/edit" modelAttribute="myModel" method="post">
    <c:forEach var=""... -------------------------->>>>> data table displayed properly
</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showSearchPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showSearch(@ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel){
    //call from db to get list of category type objects
    myModel.setCategoryList(categories);
    return "SearchPage";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchGoals(@ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(goalModel.getCategoryList());------------>> null; want this to have all objects in the list
    ..................
    return "SearchPage";
}
```

MyModel:

```
private List<Category> categoryList;
private String categorySearched;
```

Catgory:

```
private String id;
private String name;
```

As you can see on search i am returning "SearchPage" and displaying same page.

i want to re-populate drop down on Search without calling the db again. It is because i can change the search criteria again from different selection in drop down.

Please help me bind the category objects from drop down to the model. Everything else is working as expected. only when i click on search button and page reloads the drop down is not getting populated.

Comment: Hi @jasmeet24 I am interested in knowing if you found a solution to this as I am trying to accomplish the same thing. Thanks ツ

Answer (score 0):

When you are processing a `/search` request, the list of all categories is nowhere : you do not want to fetch it from the db and it did not come from the request parameters. Because when you write :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchGoals(@ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel)
```

Spring creates a new MyModel and populates it with request parameters.

If the request is simple enough, the more straightforward solution would be to cache the `getCategories(xxx)` method at service level. That way, you can call it as many times you want without reloading it from db. EhCache for example integrates nicely in Spring. Advantage : you just write in your code that you want the date and the framework deals with the caching

An alternative is to use a `@SessionAttribute`. If you add

```
@SessionAttributes("myModel")
```

above you controller class declaration, you ask Spring to store the model attribute `myModel` in session and take it from there instead of re-creating a new one on each request. It should meet your requirement but has drawbacks : there is no simple and reliable way to purge the attribute from the request when it is no longer needed. It is up to you to decide whether you can waste some session memory for that or not, depending on the number of expected simultaneous sessions, the server memory, ...

Comment: But by using path in     <form:select path="categorySearched"> i am able get the value of the selected item in drop down to my    /search request. How about i don't use session attributes and use path in jsp to store the values of the list objects displayed in the drop-down box the first time itself. In that way they would be available to me in    /search like the selected item.

Comment: @jasmeet24 : you are making a confusion between what is available while rendering a page (when JSP is processed server side) for building a response, and what is available **on next request processing**. At that moment, all model attributes not saved in session (or servlet context) are lost, and only what comes as request parameters (form input elements) can be used.